# Cannot find Repo after a morning of commiting/pulling/etc

Tags: git, github

I am a collaborator of a github organization. I have ran into an issue where git cannot find any of the remote repos. This just happened after I came back from lunch following a morning of successfully being able to commit/push/pull/etc to these repos. I have double checked my git configs by replacing user.email and user.name with a combination of associated e-mails linked to my account. I am able to access the repo through a browser as well as make pull-requests and edit, so permissions (i'm guessing) cannot be the issue.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/org/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/org/project.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access, I had to generate a [key](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and use that as my password instead of actual github password. This is due to having [2-factor enabled](https://github.com/settings/two_factor_authentication/configure).